Uniqueness of quadratic minimum subject to semidefinite constraints
Let $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ be generic. Let $M^*\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ minimize $\left\|Y - X M\right\|^2$ subject to the semidefinite constraint $M \geq 0$. Under what conditions is $M$ known to be unique?

The map $M \mapsto XM$ should be injective, equivalently $\ker X $ is trivial.

@copper.hat It's pretty clear to me that the rank of $X$ is necessary for $M$ to be unique. Why is it sufficient?

I may have commented too quickly. Just to clarify, are you minimising the objective subject to $M$ being positive definite?

Or are you saying that $M^*$ is a minimiser that happens to be $\ge 0$?

@copper.hat my bad, $M^*$ is a constrained minimizer, and the constraint is generically active.

What norm are you using (Frobenius?  Spectral?)  Is $n>p$?  $n<p$?

The Hessian of the objective is $H = 2X^{\top}X$. If $rank(X) = p$ (full column rank), then H is positive definite, implying that the objective is strongly convex in M. And hence, the minimizer is unique. This is just a sufficient condition.
